# NodeJs, Mongoose: what's the best way to check auth before update?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to check if logged-in user(req.user) is the same person who made a post(post.author, it's ObjectId refering user) before update data.
I already restrict route to the update form but I'm double checking it just in case.

This code is working, but I want to know if there is a simpler or better way to do this.

```
app.put('/posts/:id', isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
  Post.findById(req.params.id, function (err,post) {
    if(!req.user._id.equals(post.author)) return res.json({success:false, message:"Unauthrized Attempt"});
    Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.post, function (err,post) {
      res.redirect('/posts/'+req.params.id);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way.

```
app.put('/posts/:id', isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
  Post.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id,author:req.user._id}, req.body.post, function (err,post) {
    res.redirect('/posts/'+req.params.id);
  });
});
```